# How to select children from the list of matched elements?

Tags: jquery, selector, matching

This one has *really* got me confused:

I have a group of 'items' and I want to select the first `<pre>` in each group.

```
<div class="item">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h1>Test</h1>
                <pre>0</pre>
                <pre>
                    <code>1</code>
                </pre>
                <pre>
                    <code>2</code>
                </pre>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <pre>
        <code>3</code>
    </pre>
    <pre>
        <code>4</code>
    </pre>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <pre>
        <code>5</code>
    </pre>
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

My jQuery code looks like this:

```
$('.item:has(pre)').each(function(){

    text = $(this).filter('pre').html()
                  .replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;') + "<br><br>";
    $('#output').append(text);

});
```

I expect the output to be the contents of the `<pre>` blocks, but instead, I get nothing. If I use the `.size()` function on the matched elements, I get 0 every time.

The above code can be found on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/george_edison/syLMD/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.filter()` only looks at the current set of elements, whereas `.find()` looks at the descendants.

```
$('.item:has(pre)').each(function(){

    text = $(this).find('pre:first').html().replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;') + "<br><br>";
    $('#output').append(text);

});
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem of getting the *first* `<pre>` only.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('div.item pre:first-of-type').each(function(){

text = $(this).filter('pre').html().replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;') + "<br><br>";
$('#output').append(text);
});
```

Comment: **Wow!!** It works! I can't find `first-of-type` anywhere in the docs, though. Where did you find out about it?

Comment: first-of-type is a CSS3 selector, it isn’t written about in the jQuery docs but is part of the nth-of-type family of selectors

Comment: Nice answer. You won't need the `.filter('pre')` though. @George, it's not in jQuery - it will only work for browsers that support [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) - e.g. It won't work in IE7 or FF versions less than 3.5.

Comment: @Box9: I see. Your answer does what I need then.